# Problem trying to adapt the sfx "グワラ" and "ドグワン"

Tags: katakana, sound-symbolism

recently I found the sfx "グワラ" and "ドグワラ" in a Hoshino Yukinobu's manga, Munakata Kyouju Denkikou:

[image: グワン]

[image: ドグワラ]

I look in sites like thejadednetwork.com but I couldn't find anything relevant to help me adapt this sound effect.

Thank you for the help and so sorry for my bad english.

Comment: If your question was answered please click the tick box next to the answer rather than editing the title to say 'SOLVED'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both グワラ -and-  ドグワララ  perhaps グワ（グヮ） is a variant of ガ

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Middle_Japanese -- Labialized consonants /kw, gw/ appeared during Early Middle Japanese. During this period, labialized consonants preceding -i and -e merged with their non-labial counterparts.[8]

- グワラ --> ガラ ---- ガラガラ... is a common onomatopoeia for earthquakes, or a building collapsing.
- ドグワララ --> ドガララ ... would be a similar sound. Are those lightening bolts?

> http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~hi5k-stu/nihongo/kanji.htm
>
> - （注４）
>     「クワ」の発音　：ラフカディオ・ハーン（小泉八雲）の『怪談』は、旧仮名で書くなら「くわいだん」である。『怪談』は英語で書かれていて、その原題は「Kwaidan」である。「クワ」の発音が「kwa」なのがわかるだろう。
> - （注５）
>     「怪」は中国語「クアイguai」で、旧仮名「クワイkwai」、新仮名「カイkai」。日本での「クワkwa」と言う発音は、中国語の「gua」がルーツの一つだったのである。

Comment: Yes, the second pic has lightening bolts in the background, then now I know what it does mean, thank you.